# On Android play audio located on PC(Windows) in flac format

Tags: audio-player

I want to have all `.flac` files on a Windows PC, but play them on an android, through LAN(both PC and phone are connected to the same network).

Requirements:

- Much preferably free. Though, if our dear friends pirates have it, that should do.
- Additional server program can be tolerable.
- Tracking also can be tolerable

Comment: While waiting for answers, be welcome to see my coresponding app listing: [Online & Network Player](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_network). Not sure which one supports Flac, though.

Comment: it seems that foobar2000 with foo_upnp plugin should do the job, as it also my fav audio player. I'll give the feedback some time later